# How to debug app in Ipad?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, debugging, cordova

I’ve created an app and installed it on my iPad. Unfortunately part of the functionality is not working: when I press a certain button, it should execute some JS code, but this is not the case. In the tool which I use for creating it, there’s no bug, no exception, nothing that leads to an error. This is the same in Chrome using the Developer Tools.

Since the tool allows me to generate the file for Android, I installed the app in my Samsung Galaxy SII and Nexus 7. It works perfectly there!

I think it must be a problem with PhoneGap. Is there any tool for debugging the app on the iPad (not within Xcode)?

Answer (score 1):

If relevant logs are being generated, it is possible to connect the device to a Mac and see the general console, where you'll see these logs (amongst many other system related events)

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the info but I read about it in the internet. Unfortunately I have no Mac, only Windows.

Comment: if you have no mac, then are u trying to debugging it on the emulator? Not all working functions on a normal web-browser work on Phonegap, or at least in the same performance ;)
please check the following link:


http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/iphone-development-windows-options-available/

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed Safari for Windows and found the bug. Unfortunately there´s no version 6 for Windows so that I can use the newest developer tools.